# TFS 2013 - Clean workspace vs Clean build

Tags: tfs, build

I couldn't find definitive answer: What is the difference in TFS2013 betwenn **Clean workspace** True/False and **Clean build** True/False. It's not easy to catch the build server while working and see really what's happening. I think that the difference is that clean workapce will delete the `src` directory, while the clean build will delete the `bin`/`tst` dirs.

If it so - I can't understand why is there need to delete the `src` directory though. It seems that the cleanst way to do build requires only to clean the work tree (along with `bin`/`tst`) and get latest above it, and not **deleting it** and get **all the sources** again.

If so - how can I perform this type of cleaning? Or I understood it wrong?

The background is that we have heavy sources (>1GB) and not very good network between the tfs server and the build server. We would glad to cut it off, but also clean the `src` tree before the build.

Answer (score 1):

For "Clean Workspace" setting, there are three options. And this setting is used to set whether to delete source/output folders in the build agent working directly. (by default is: $(SystemDrive)\Builds\$(BuildAgentId)\$(BuildDefinitionPath))

1. **All**: delete all existing outputs and sources and do a full rebuild;
2. **Outputs**: to delete all existing outputs but get only those source files that have changed since the last build (Incremental Get);
3. **None**: to leave existing outputs and sources in place and build any changes incrementally.

However, I can't find **Clean Build** (True|False) setting, do you mean delete builds or Retention Policy?

For your scenario, you need to set "Clean Workspace" to be "Output", then the output folder is deleted but still have source folder.

Comment: I think the OP is referring to the "Process" tab in the build definition in VS, I get the same (true/false) options for both clean workspace & clean build in my screen..

Comment: Keyword here is Team Foundation Server; not Visual Studio. Allan is correct.